# How to change automatically changed numeric value from date format to numeric in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-2016

I have a problem with my 78 thousands row document in Excel [using Excel 2016]. When i got it, the numeric data was changed into date because it was decimal with a dot.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPDLn.jpg)

Is it possible to changed that date format to number without changing the cells value? [like in picture from 2.1 changed into date format back to 2,1?]

Comment: Most likely you are opening a text document, .csv or .txt.  you need to use the wizard/power pivot to import the document and make the column Text before opening.  Just opening the text file, Excel will try to convert anything that looks like a date as such.

Comment: @ScottCraner I did not mention it but its pure excel file which i have trouble with. But thank you :)

Comment: If that is the case then it is a date before you open it and you should have whomever gave you the file fix the issue.  Because you will have a mix of dates and text, anything that could be converted to a date already has been and the rest will be text.  You can try: `=IFERROR(--(MONTH(A1)&",",&DAY(A1)),NUMBERVALUE(A1,"."))`